# MongoDB : Cloning Database error?

Tags: mongodb

When I try to clone my mongo database from other machine, I see the following on client

```
 db.cloneDatabase('10.10.124.110')
{ "errmsg" : "query failed staging.system.namespaces", "ok" : 0 }
```

and on server I see

```
Thu Nov 10 11:29:01 [conn10] assertion 10057 unauthorized db:staging lock type:-1 client:10.10.124.110 ns:staging.system.namespaces query:{}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

That error seems a lot like this one https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2846 where an error is thrown because **copyDatabase()** ... which **cloneDatabase()** uses ... requires Admin privileges. In that case the user is using a hosted MongoDB instance where they didn't have admin privileges.

You can see some more about how to use the **copyDatabase()** command [here](http://learnmongo.com/posts/quick-tip-copy-dbs-between-servers/) and [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Copy+Database+Commands).

So, for example if you are using -auth a username/password you'll need to run the **copyDatabase()** command like this:

```
> db.copyDatabase(from_db, to_db, from_host, username, password);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to just resolve this error by querying the PRIMARY host in a replicaSet, rather than the SECONDARY.